# What is ERT for?

Tags: ert

I'm still a little confused about ERT. Is it for running regression tests of your elisp code or for running regression tests of other code too?

For example would I run my JUnit tests under ERT, and ERT would display the results, jump to the failures, and rerun specific tests?

Comment: @wasamasa If you don't want to be helpful, please don't answer. https://github.com/nlamirault/gotest.el/blob/master/README.md seems to run go test with ERT.

Comment: That is for testing the gotest package...

Comment: So this is just ERF testing the Go testing mode? ugh.

Comment: ERT is only for running Emacs Lisp code. It has minimal command-line interface and some more features when run from Emacs interactively. It may be possible to reuse ERT's interactive part for running other tests, but as it currently stands, it wouldn't be a great idea since many other testing tools have more features than ERT can display, though it would be nice to have a unified unit test interface in Emacs.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `info` -> <kbd>g</kbd> `(ert)`.

> ERT is a tool for automated testing in Emacs Lisp.  Its main features
>   are facilities for defining tests, running them and reporting the
>   results, and for debugging test failures interactively.
>
> ERT is similar to tools for other environments such as JUnit, but has
>   unique features that take advantage of the dynamic and interactive
>   nature of Emacs.  Despite its name, it works well both for test-driven
>   development (see
>   `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development') and for
>   traditional software development methods.

Reading info pages is a very useful Emacs skill. It's wise to learn it.